# Laravel crud show on empty

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have a laravel crud with relations. but when i want to load the page some table rows dont have a value. and this gives the error: 'Attempt to read property "name" on null'

But how do i ignore this message and keep loading in the page?

index.blade:

```
    @foreach($files as $file)
        <tr>
            <td>{{$file->id}}</td>
            <td>{{$file->title}} </td>
            <td>{{$file->description_short}} </td>
            <td>{{$file->description_long}} </td>
            <td>{{$file->file}}</td>
            <td>{{$file->language->name}} </td>
            <td>{{$file->subfolder->name}} </td>
          
            <td>{{$file->role->name}} </td>
            <td>
                <a href="{{ route('admin.file.edit',$file->id)}}" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <form action="{{ route('admin.file.destroy', $file->id)}}" method="post">
                  @csrf
                  @method('DELETE')
                  <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit">Delete</button>
                </form>
            </td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

controller:

```
 public function index()
    {
        $files = File::with('subfolder', 'language', 'tag')->get();
        $languages = Language::all();
        $tags = Tag::all();
        $subfolders = Subfolder::all();
        $users = User::all();    
        return view('admin.file.index', compact('files', 'languages', 'tags', 'users', 'subfolders'));
    }
```

i want the index to ignore all the NULL properties

Comment: Try using {{@$file->language->name}}

Comment: you are a hero, now it works. thanks

Comment: Also, same can be arise on subfolder and role column, so @ can be added there also. If want to display  a default text like "NA", can be done like ,  @$file->subfolder->name?:"NA" .

Comment: @Delanovanlonden check whether using `@` ignore `$file->language->name` even `name` has a value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `@` before your php Variable will work for you like below.

```
{{@$file->language->name}}
```

Comment: As I remember, `@` will completely suppress the variable, even if it has value.

Comment: Correct @AbdullaNilam, But  Check the OP's comment "i want the index to ignore all the NULL properties" , So, else I had your answer in my mind already

Comment: *all the NULL properties* doesn't mean values in it

Answer (score 1):

And also, by using

```
{{ $file->language->name ?? '' }} # typical PHP way
{{ $file->language?->name }} # if object/relation "language" exist then access "name" propery
```

---

### Note:

When you use `@` to the variable `{{@$file->language->name}}`, we're skipping the error message. This means we're telling Laravel to ***"Leave this Variable alone"***. And ***It's not the best way to check if empty***

Answer (score 1):

There are various ways:

- Error control operator:

  `@$file->language->name` the `@` operator suppress the errors messages (imho not very clean :) , but same result)

  From [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php):

  ```
  // Note: The @-operator works only on expressions. A simple rule of thumb   is: if one can take the value of something, then one can prepend the @ operator to it.
  // For instance, it can be prepended to variables, functions calls, certain language construct calls (e.g. include), and so forth. 
  // It cannot be prepended to function or class definitions, or conditional structures such as if and foreach, and so forth.
  ```

- *Classical* ternary operator way

  `$file->language ? $file->language->name : null;`

- From **PHP7+** : Null Coalescing Operator

  `$file->language->name ?? null;`

- From **PHP8+** : null safe Operator

  `$file->language?->name;` (amazing! :-))

Answer (score 0):

Laravel has a built-in helper for this, called `optional()`.

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/helpers#method-optional

```
<td>{{ optional($file->language)->name }} </td>
```

> The `optional` function accepts any argument and allows you to access properties or call methods on that object. If the given object is `null`, properties and methods will return `null` instead of causing an error.